# Formik form with useFormik throwing error for value <input/> field but not for materialUI <TextField/> properties

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, formik-material-ui

I am building a form and getting an error that I don't quite understand.

When I use a TextField from Material UI like this

```
<TextField
                fullWidth
                id="name"
                name="name"
                label="Name"
                type="name"
                value={formik.values.name}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                error={formik.touched.name && Boolean(formik.errors.name)}
                helperText={formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name}
            />
```

No errors come up and the output and behavior are as expected.

When I use a label and an input from the [Formik useFormik docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) like this

```
<label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.name}
                />
```

I get the following error

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2118, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
(JSX attribute) InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.value?: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined
```

I wanted to try the simplest input field from formik useFormik to understand how the state of each input field is being updated using `value` and `onChange`, but I can't seem to translate TextField into a basic input without this error :/

Comment: I can't replicate your error. I don't see any TS errors when I use input box: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-tdd-7ozi9?file=/src/App.tsx
Which version of formik are you using?

Comment: Looks like your initialValue for the `names` is null . You should not be passing null to `input`.  change your initial value to empty string `name: ''`